# rubocop failing with Rails 6 and Ruby 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I created a pristine new rails app (`rails new myapp`), using Rails 6.1.7.7 and Ruby 3.0.6p216. I’m on an Apple M2 Pro running Sonoma 14.2.

I installed rubocop and added it to the Gemfile.

```
rvm @global do gem install rubocop
```

Trying to execute `rubocop` either with or without `bundle exec`, I get errors.
rubocop is in my path,

```
myapp % which rubocop
/Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.6/bin/rubocop
```

running `rubocop` gives me a recursion error (in a pristine rails app)

```
myapp % rubocop
/Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.6/lib/ruby/3.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:128:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Scalar': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from /Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.6/lib/ruby/3.0.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit’
```

also with `bundle exec`:

```
myapp % bundle exec rubocop
bundler: failed to load command: rubocop (/Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.6/bin/rubocop)
/Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.6/lib/ruby/3.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:52:in `deserialize': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from /Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.6/lib/ruby/3.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:128:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Scalar'
```

I tried getting rid of psych but it is considered a default.

```
myapp % gem uninstall psych
Gem psych-3.3.2 cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  I spent a lot of time looking for a recursion problem in my code now to find out this error also occurs for a brand new rails app. I no longer think it is a code problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **full** stack traces to in each of your commands. Psych is a library to parse YAML data. If there is a `SystemStackError` there, it's very likely caused by some invalid YAML somewhere. The full stack trace should point to the code location where this invalid YAML is parsed which helps to fix it.

Comment: It could be you have some kind of wonky `rubocop.yml` YAML here that's defining some kind of self-recursive structure.

Comment: This may not solve your issue, but why are you using outdated versions of Rails and Ruby for a new app?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/issues/5118#issuecomment-346876567

I think this one should fix your problem. If you already have .rubocop.yml file then you should check for correctness and fix this yml file